# Disabling Web UI for hdfs namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a configuration to disable HTTP commands to HDFS ? In absence of Kerberos, I am trying to disable the HTTP access to files in HDFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebHDFS should be disabled by default. You can disable WebHDFS by modifying your hdfs-site.xml by adding the following between the `<configuration>` and `</configuration>` tags.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Enable or disable webhdfs. Defaults to false</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Adding this worked. No more able to browse/download files.